# sqlplus connect without typing the @local_SID when only have one instance

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

Every time I want to connect with a user in Sqlplus I have to specify the database|sid name too,

```
SQL>connect scott/tiger@orcl
```

I have installed another database for other purpose but I removed it.
Before the installation of second database I could connect without using *@orcl* but after I removed it I have to connect that way I said.
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What OS are you using?

Check what the environment ORACLE_SID is set to.  Change it to the existing one and you won't be needing to specify the connection string anymore.

Comment: That should be it.

Second database installation probably modified environment settings, changing ORACLE_SID to point to the second (and now, non-existant) database.

Comment: @dezso I'm using Windows 8.1 Enterprise 64bit.Where is the environment that I can edit it?

Comment: There is a registry key named ORACLE_SID in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ORACLE\KEY_HOME_NAME that its value was "testdb" and I changed it to "orcl".Now I can connect without using @orcl.thanks.

Comment: In oracle docs said that we can use this command too:  
set PATH=%ORACLE_HOME%\bin;%PATH%